# What light bulb can be used for the Frigidaire upright freezer FFFH20F2QW?

Tags: appliances, bulb, freezer

The lightbulb on my freezer went out, the freezer is a Frigidaire FFFH20F2QW. I've tested the actual socket, and it seems to be working, so I'm pretty sure it must be the bulb.

I see the the official replacement bulb is part number 5304517886. This part is an LED bulb that is relatively expensive.

- Is there any other part that fits?
- Is the base a standard socket size?
- Is there an incandescent part number that is cheaper?

I've tried to google for the above answers, but wasn't able to find clear answers. Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick googling suggests you are dealing with an Edison E17 type base.  This is the third most common base in North America, after E27 (normal) and E10 (candelabra).  17 = diameter in millimeters (think slightly smaller than 3/4").

You should be able to be able to use any 120V LED bulb with an E17 base. Be wary of mail order *especially* Amazon.

I would not use an incandescent bulb because the freezer's socket area may not be built for the heat of an incandescent.

Comment: I also googled around, and numerous amazon reviews stated that it was a unique/proprietary thread size. After your response, i just grabbed an existing E17 bulb from another appliance, and it did fit fine. Thank you!

Comment: The E17 is commonly referred to as "Appliance Bulb". The funny thing is that while the incandescent versions were built for "all extremes", the LED versions are *great* for refrigerators/freezers but useless (because LEDs don't like 350 degrees F) for ovens.

Comment: @Jeremy Yeah, many Amazon sellers do fake reviews (that's what "brushing" is all about). Amazon just ceased to be reliable for electrical gear of any kind.